# Vue sanitize a href url

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sonarqube

So guys I have an issue like `Make sure bypassing Vue built-in sanitization is safe here.` with a href URL in vue js, which the URL i get from my API, and then I've tried to sanitize using `@braintree/sanitize-url` and then put it inside my `Vue.prototype.$sanitize` like this

```js
import { sanitizeUrl } from "@braintree/sanitize-url"

Vue.prototype.$sanitize = sanitizeUrl
```

and then i used it on my component like this

```js
data: () => ({
  sanitizeUrl: null
}),
created() {
  // BEFORE SANITIZE : "https://codepen.io/"
  // AFTER SANITIZED : "https://codepen.io/"

  this.sanitizeUrl = this.$sanitize(this.obj.info.url)
}
```

```html
<a
  :href="sanitizeUrl"
  target="_blank"
  rel="noreferrer noopener nofollow"
/>
```

everything's good but the sonar cloud still detects this URL is not sanitized yet
like `Make sure bypassing Vue built-in sanitization is safe here.`

how can I sanitize this URL from my API? Thank you guys

Comment: try `:href="$sanitize(sanitizeUrl)"` and remove `this.$sanitize` from `created`?

Comment: @XinheWang, Thank you. I've tried this way, but it still has the same error

Comment: @bukandicki can you share the url after and before you sanitize with braintree sanitizer ?. Just to confirm it is sanitize and how the url looks like after and before.

Comment: sure, i just update my question @rohin-arka

Comment: Did you checked the logs what you are getting `before` and `after` of using  `this.$sanitize(this.obj.info.url)` ?

Comment: @bukandicki The braintree sanitizeUrl function is doing its job `https://github.com/braintree/sanitize-url (in the documentation you can see how it works)` and the url you posted in question is also sanitized but I am not sure what sonar cloud is looking for. Can you post the exact error thrown by sonar cloud ?.

Comment: Sonar Cube says "Make sure bypassing Vue built-in sanitization is safe here."
I suppose you can't fix this error in the code. You should be sure that your code is safe and you can change a status of it to "Safe" in the SQ report. Not sure if it possible to acknowledge the error in IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Using this help me to clear the bug

```
:href="sanitizeUrl ? sanitizeUrl : ''"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.